# rvm with svn bindings

Tags: ruby, svn, rvm

System ruby on Mac OS X has the svn bindings (`require 'svn/client'`) built in.  However, I need to use RVM, which doesn't have the svn bindings.  How can I get svn bindings into RVM's ruby?

Comment: have you tried one of the gems `gem list -r svn` ?

Comment: @mpapis yes. the most popular one, svn_wc, requires the svn bindings to be installed.  some of the other ones either don't work or are severely underdocumented.